How to run a test between two or more groups when each data point brings a confidence interval?
I have recently started working on a dataset, but my limited experience as a recent graduate is preventing me from making progress. After performing a rarefaction (a form of bootstrapping), which was necessary for the project, I now have a dataframe with 24 species diversity indices, each accompanied by a confidence interval generated from the random rarefaction process.
These 24 diversity indices belong to 2 different non-independent groups that I need to compare. If there were no confidence intervals and I could work solely with the means, I would use a paired t-test. I have 12 plots (and so 12 rarefied diversity indices) with the treatment 1 and 12 non-independent (spatially correlated) plots with the treatment 2. I want to test if diversity is different along treatment. I would treat it like a t-test but rarefaction/bootstrapping gives me a confidence interval alongside my indices.
To account for the confidence intervals obtained through rarefaction, I tried performing a weighted t-test using the variance derived from the interval. However, I am not confident in my method and cannot find any articles online that support this approach.
This is my dataframe:
size1 <- c(32.67256,30.59280,33.56214,30.15552,29.02073,24.92427,34.79967,34.26559,29.33457,25.75716,27.91638,33.87884)
size2 <-c(34.18847,30.94369,37.38462,22.96785,27.98805,31.39834,30.26401,33.59788,36.19856,31.19667,21.27245,28.87137)
size <-c(size1, size2)
size1CI05 <-c(29.50177,26.23491,29.60487,25.94388,24.48941,21.78924,29.24082,28.09738,25.20056,21.21051,24.40705,30.08490)
size2CI05 <-c(29.51654,23.75201,31.29203,17.60071,21.92296,26.38236,23.69115,26.15880,26.44932,26.72620,17.48761,23.76434)
sizeCI05 <-c(size1CI05,size2CI05)
size1CI95 <-c(35.84336,34.95070,37.51941,34.36716,33.55205,28.05929,40.35851,40.43380,33.46857,30.30381,31.42571,37.67278) 
size2CI95 <-c(38.86039,38.13538,43.47722,28.33500,34.05315,36.41432,36.83687,41.03696,45.94780,35.66713,25.05730,33.97840)
sizeCI95 <-c(size1CI95,size2CI95)
group <- c(c(rep("1", 12), rep("2", 12))
df <- data.frame(size, sizeCI05, sizeCI95, group)

I also add the dput output as asked:
df <-structure(list(size = c(32.67256, 30.5928, 33.56214, 30.15552, 
29.02073, 24.92427, 34.79967, 34.26559, 29.33457, 25.75716, 27.91638, 
33.87884, 34.18847, 30.94369, 37.38462, 22.96785, 27.98805, 31.39834, 
30.26401, 33.59788, 36.19856, 31.19667, 21.27245, 28.87137), 
    size05CI = c(29.5017662019491, 26.2349058385758, 29.6048735822698, 
    25.9438818737996, 24.4894140422372, 21.7892435074709, 29.2408246478003, 
    28.097376313181, 25.2005633026381, 21.2105115402011, 24.4070457401779, 
    30.0849045894848, 29.5165407340379, 23.7520071901393, 31.2920265619889, 
    17.6007091843407, 21.9229562124319, 26.3823600157115, 23.6911524798744, 
    26.158796800294, 26.4493176960902, 26.7262037524753, 17.4876088906701, 
    23.7643440166671), size95CI = c(35.8433590913617, 34.9506991382152, 
    37.5194133001315, 34.3671592174968, 33.5520534941053, 28.0592932279925, 
    40.3585126169722, 40.4338032764411, 33.4685713521404, 30.303809204322, 
    31.4257104335821, 37.6727751129716, 38.8603902871733, 38.1353758799793, 
    43.4772171945701, 28.3349990423006, 34.0531465846994, 36.4143170389483, 
    36.8368654619253, 41.0369594182707, 45.9478039221974, 35.6671344715295, 
    25.0572999101401, 33.9783955274194), group = c("1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
    "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))

This is what I tried to do:
install.packages("weights", dependencies=TRUE)
library(weights)
SE1 <- (size1CI95-size1CI05)/3.919928
SE2 <- (size2CI95-size2CI05)/3.919928
sizepaired <- size1-size2
combSE <- sqrt(SE1^2+SE2^2)
weights <- 1/combSE^2
wtd.t.test(x=sizepaired, y=0, weight=weights)

My approach was to take into account for the confidence interval (i.e., the standard deviation) originated due to rarefaction in my test by using a weighted test, where the weights are derived from the standard deviation. However, I am uncertain whether this is a valid approach, and I have not found any scientific articles addressing this method. My colleagues are somewhat skeptical and would prefer not to use 'experimental' methods.
Moreover, I am currently using a parametric test, but among my data (which I have not included here), some do not follow a normal distribution. Thus, I should consider how to conduct a weighted paired non-parametric test
As asked I'm editing with my raw data (how many individuals in each plot):
df <-structure(list(Group1_RH = c(16L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 
0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 14L, 16L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 
6L, 15L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Group2_RH = c(5L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 
    5L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Group1_VA = c(9L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 31L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 13L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 5L, 0L, 15L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Group2_VA = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Group1_FO = c(6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 20L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 22L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Group2_FO = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Group1_AI = c(6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Group2_AI = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Group1_AZ = c(8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Group2_AZ = c(6L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 4L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Group1_LU = c(3L, 0L, 2L, 
    8L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Group2_LU = c(2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 13L, 
    4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Group1_ME = c(7L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 
    13L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    6L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Group2_ME = c(12L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Group1_CA = c(6L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 
    6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Group2_CA = c(3L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 
    7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Group1_CR = c(6L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 
    6L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 15L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Group2_CR = c(2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Group1_VG = c(11L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 
    5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Group2_VG = c(3L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 11L, 
    11L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L), Group1_MZ = c(8L, 
    0L, 0L, 4L, 30L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 17L, 
    6L, 1L, 23L, 4L, 26L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Group2_MZ = c(0L, 
    13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
    5L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 8L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 20L), Group1_GO = c(3L, 
    0L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 16L, 
    2L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Group2_GO = c(10L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 14L, 
    11L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Aegithalos_caudatus", 
"Alauda_arvensis", "Alcedo_atthis", "Anas_crecca", "Anas_platyrhynchos", 
"Anthus_pratensis", "Anthus_spinoletta", "Ardea_alba", "Ardea_cinerea", 
"Botaurus_stellaris", "Bubulcus_ibis", "Carduelis_carduelis", 
"Certhia_brachydactyla", "Chloris_chloris", "Chroicocephalus_ridibundus", 
"Coccothraustes_coccothraustes", "Coloeus_monedula", "Columba_livia", 
"Columba_palumbus", "Corvus_cornix", "Corvus_corone", "Cyanistes_caeruleus", 
"Dendrocopos_major", "Dryobates_minor", "Dryocopus_martius", 
"Egretta_garzetta", "Emberiza_cia", "Emberiza_citrinella", "Emberiza_schoeniclus", 
"Erithacus_rubecula", "Fringilla_coelebs", "Fringilla_montifringilla", 
"Fulica_atra", "Gallinago_gallinago", "Gallinula_chloropus", 
"Garrulus_glandarius", "Linaria_cannabina", "Motacilla_alba", 
"Motacilla_cinerea", "Netta_rufina", "Parus_major", "Passer_montanus", 
"Phalacrocorax_carbo", "Phylloscopus_collybita", "Phasianus_colchicus", 
"Phoenicurus_ochruros", "Periparus_ater", "Pica_pica", "Picus_viridis", 
"Poecile_palustris", "Prunella_modularis", "Psittacula_krameri", 
"Rallus_aquaticus", "Regulus_ignicapilla", "Regulus_regulus", 
"Saxicola_rubicola", "Serinus_serinus", "Sitta_europaea", "Spatula_clypeata", 
"Spinus_spinus", "Streptopelia_decaocto", "Sturnus_vulgaris", 
"Sylvia_atricapilla", "Tachybaptus_ruficollis", "Troglodytes_troglodytes", 
"Turdus_iliacus", "Turdus_merula", "Turdus_philomelos", "Turdus_pilaris", 
"Vanellus_vanellus"))
library(iNEXT)
abbcove <-estimateD(df,q=0,datatype="abundance",base="coverage",nboot=1000)

In the abbcove object you can find qD (diversity index), qD.LCL (lower bound of confidence interval for the diversity index) and qd.UCL (upper bound of confidence interval for the diversity index)

Could you please explain what you mean by "random rarefaction process"?

@whuber is a statistical technique used to estimate species diversity by standardizing sample sizes to account for differences in sampling effort. For example, if I had two samples, one with 150 individuals and one with 300, I would standardize by bringing both samples to 150. This means that for the larger sample, I would randomly create many subsets of 150 individuals until I obtain a mean rarefied diversity value and a confidence interval.

That sounds like it would be inferior to almost any statistical technique that employed all the data.

@RuiBarradas I added the dput output, I hope this is what you needed

@whuber rarefaction is widely used in ecology, and there are many articles on the subject because, as far as I know, it would be ecologically incorrect to use the entire dataset. In any case, I am open to hearing any ideas.

I believe rarefaction can be understood as a form of bootstrapping rather than "bringing both samples to 150."  This helps validate it while indicating the limits of its applicability.  Regardless, much rests on what specifically you mean by "working on" these data.  What are you trying to do exactly?  Is it really just a comparison of two group means, as indicated in your question?  Could you perhaps provide a small example of the data and illustrate what you're trying to do?

Can you provide additional details? What exactly is the "size" you have as your primary metric? What does it measure. Also, why are the 2 groups paired? (since you mention paired t-test).  W/o it, it is very hard to understand your data/analysis. Thanks

@whuber I'm not very knowledgeable about bootstrapping but rarefaction indeed is a form of bootstrapping, I was trying to keep the language easy when giving the example. Moving on, size1 and size2 are diversity indices, they represent how diverse is the community in a plot. I have 12 plots (and 12 rarefied diversity indices) with a similar treatment (group 1) and 12 non-indipendent plots with another treatment (group 2). I want to test if diversity is different along treatment. I would treat it like a t-test but rarefaction/bootstrapping gives me a confidence interval alongside my indices.

@jginestet the metric is a diversity index used in ecology, the groups are paired because they have a strong spatial correlation (treatment 1 and treatment 2 were tested in the same area)

Please add new information as an edit to the post, not only as comments! Comments on this site are ephemeral, often seen by few people (specifically not necessarily by the ones you are answering!), and can be deleted

@kjetilbhalvorsen ok thank you, I edited adding some info

Do you have the original samples on which the confidence intervals are based? That'd be much better. (Note in particular that people not knowing "rarefaction" will not really know precisely what can be done with the confidence intervals.)

It may well be possible to model this as a mixed effects model with a fixed effect for the difference between the two groups, a random effect for the pairing, and a random effect for "within-species sampling". Having the original observations, it should be possible to fit this and test the fixed effect. It may in principle also be possible just having confidence intervals, but out of the top of my head I don't know how.

@ChristianHennig I edited with the original observations and the command I used to compute diversity indices and confidence intervals. One of my colleagues suggested using mixed models too, I really don't know how to make the pairing or the confidence interval a random effect though.

The help page of estimateD doesn't give any references, and I have no idea what exactly it does. But the computation  of these confidence intervals doesn't seem to be what I had in mind it would be, and this means that chances are my original idea how to set up a mixed effects model here may not work, or may not do what you need even if it works. Another thought is that you may ask yourself how much information is actually lost ignoring the confidence intervals for this task, and how much of a problem this actually is.

@ChristianHennig Thank you very much for your time. I considered performing a separate t-test solely on the standard deviations that I can calculate from the confidence intervals. This way, I would support the analyses conducted only on the estimates. Do you have any suggestions for tests that could help quantify how much information I would lose by ignoring the confidence intervals?

This is a question that can only be addressed by knowing the subject matter, aim of analysis etc. "Testing how much information you lose" would be more complicated than knowing how to use the information, because obviously as long as there is no way to use the information, there's nothing you win by it.

From what I gather (I am no ecology domain expert, for sure), the diversity index you compute is just the number of non-zero species (observations) in your samples. The index is $n_i$, number of unique bird specie observations out of a grand total of $N_i$ observations at this site. Or something proportional to $n_i$, e.g. $\frac {n_i} {N_i}$. Am I correct ??

@jginestet yes, it's simply the number of unique species
